# Setting SECRET_KEY as enviorment variable

Tags: django

I'm trying to set the secret key as an environment variable. I followed exactly as instructed however  get `500 Internal Server Error`

**settings.py**

```
import os
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
```

Then I run: `export SECRET_KEY='<my secret key>'`

Followed by: `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: looks like the wrong order to me. 1.) export secret_key='password'; in a linux shell 2.) django-admin runserver with same shell instance (apache is usually just a proxy)

Comment: can you provide the traceback?

Comment: @MichaelD.When I run `django-admin` I get `    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line ImportError: No module named django.core.management`